# How will changing the InfoPath List Reference affect old saved forms

Tags: infopath

I have created a form in InfoPath on a SharePoint site that refers to a List on that site for data. The form has been used for years and there are many old forms saved. I need to update the List name as it no longer applies to the organization (my mistake for being too specific back when I created the form). My question is, if I change the List name and repoint the template to gather data from that list's fields, will it kill my ability to read my old forms which still use that same template in the form library? I don't want to create a whole new form library and template, but the List name if misleading to the users.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you can do a few things.  Typically, the renaming of a list is only cosmetic, in that the actual URL to the list doesn't change.  That would mean your forms are ok.  However, if you do need to change it, the old forms will be pointing to the old form template file.

So, you can try the SharePoint built in method of relinking the forms, but I've had problems there in the past.  Ultimately I had to download all of the form files and grep them to replace the old URL with the new one.  That usually works just fine though.

On Windows, WinGrep can do this very easily and quickly with thousands of infopath xml files.